# Spring Integration Message Router ability to log output channel Destination name

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We're using Spring Integration 4.2.0.  We have a flow that uses a Message `Router` and have a desire to be able to log where a message was routed to (actual `Destination` name and ideally `Destination` type along with the raw payload).  In our case our routers have output channels which have `JmsSendingMessageHandler`'s as endpoints.
What we would like to see is something like this in our logs:

```
[INFO ] message routed to [amq | queue://QUEUE1] : This is a message!
[INFO ] message routed to [wmq | queue://QUEUE2] : This is also a message!
[INFO ] message routed to [ems | queue://QUEUE3] : This is also a message!
[INFO ] message routed to [wmq | topic://TOPIC1] : This is also a message!
```

The router config is similar to this:

```
<int:router id="messageRouter"
    input-channel="inputChannel"
    resolution-required="false"
    ref="messageRouterServiceImpl"
    method="route"
    default-output-channel="unroutedChannel">
    <int:mapping value="channelAlias1" channel="channel1" />
    <int:mapping value="channelAlias2" channel="channel2" />
    <int:mapping value="channelAlias3" channel="channel3" />  
    <int:mapping value="routerErrorChannel" channel="routerErrorChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="nullChannel" channel="nullChannel"/>
</int:router>
```

I have a solution for achieving this but I'll admit it is a bit ugly as it queries the Spring `ApplicationContext` then uses reflection to ultimately obtain the `Destination`'s name.
Alternatively I suppose I could put a logger at the front of every channel that the router outputs to but was trying to avoid repeatedly having to remember to do this for every flow that we use a router in.

I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions for a cleaner way of doing this.  I can share my code if you'd like.  Perhaps Spring Integration Java DSL would help with this?

Comment: It should be pretty straight forward. Can you share any one of your channel code along with messageRouterServiceImpl class.

Answer (score 0):

The one of point where you can hook is `<int:wire-tap>` - a global `ChannelInterceptor` for the particular channels by the pattern for their name.

This `WireTap` may send messages to the `<int:logging-channel-adapter>` or any other custom service to log via desired way or do anything else.

Another good out-of-the-box feature for you is `<int:message-history>`. With that you will have a `path` how message has traveled through your flow, including the routing logic. You can find it as a part of the `MessageHeaders`.

Comment: This is helpful, but unfortunately I don't think it fully solves my use case.  I guess I really have two questions: 1) How can i get the JMS Destinations for the starting point (source) and ending point (sink) of a flow (assuming the flow has both of those)?  2) When using a "ref" for a Spring Integration bean (i.e. in above ref="messageRouterServiceImpl") is there an easy way for the object being referenced to get a handle to the object that's referencing it?  I my case it would be useful for the messageRouterServiceImpl to have a handle to the router that's instantiated injected into it.

Comment: 1) You can do that only carrying them in the `MessageHeaders`. Then  you can use them in your log service to format log message properly.

Comment: The second your question isn't clear to me. Sorry... You can play with the `publish-subscribe-channel` for the `JmsSendingMessageHandler`. Some `DestinationService` which you will use from the `JmsSendingMessageHandler`'s `destination-expression` and `ThreadLocal` to store the desired `Destination`. You its value from the second subscriber to log and clear `ThreadLocal`. Yes, it might not be so clear, too, but I should admit that it is difficult to help people with their extraordinary tasks, when they expect some out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, you want

- router to log this information after successfully sending the message to  expected destination.
- You do not want to put loggers, as it will be forced to have for every new flow attached to router

One approach which I can think of is-

1- Extend MethodInvokingRouter for your custom router implementation.

2- Override handleMessageInternal method from AbstractMessageRouter class.

Here is the code snippet-

```
public class CustomRouter extends MethodInvokingRouter {

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomRouter.class);

Map<Message<?>,String> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public CustomRouter(Object object, Method method) {
    super(object, method);
}

public CustomRouter(Object object, String methodName) {
    super(object, methodName);
}

public CustomRouter(Object object) {
    super(object);
}

public String route(Message<?> message) {
    String destinationName = null;
    /*
     * Business logic to get destination name
     */

    destinationName = "DERIVED VALUE AS PER THE ABOVE BUSINESS LOGIC";
    //NOTE:- here also we can log (optimistic way of saying that messages are being routed to...), but at this point of time we are not sure whether the returned string value will get resolved to a message channel and message will be routed to the destination. 

    //Put that name to map so that it can be extracted later on in handleMessageInternal method
    m.put(message, destinationName); // O(1) complexity
    return destinationName;         
} 



@Override
protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) {
    super.handleMessageInternal(message);
    //At this point we are quit sure that channel has been resolved and message has been sent to destination

    /*
     * get the destination name returned from route method from populated map 
     * 
     * As at this point we know whatever return value was (from route method), there exists a message channel.
     * 
     */
    String key = m.get(message);
    // get the key-value pair for channel mapping
    Map<String,String> mappedChannelMap = super.getChannelMappings();

    // get destination name where message is routed
    String destinationName = mappedChannelMap.get(key);   // O(1) complexity 

    //Now log to a file as per the requirement
    log.info("message routed to "+destinationName+" Message is- "+message.getPayload().toString());

}
```

}

I haven't tried this piece of code, there may exist some improvement. What's your thought...